# SQL work with 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have a dataset with football results (French Championship) like this:

[image: Pandas dataframe related to dataset]

How can I deal with the fact that a team can be either in 'HomeTeam' or 'AwayTeam' ?

I've done this to retrieve all teams but I don't know if it's the best way.

```
SELECT HomeTeam as Team 
FROM data 
UNION 
SELECT AwayTeam 
FROM data
```

If I want to count how many match each Team has played, do I have to check the result using 'HomeTeam' and sum the result from 'AwayTeam' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table, `GROUP BY` on it's result.

```
select team, count(*)
from
(
SELECT HomeTeam as Team FROM data 
UNION ALL
SELECT AwayTeam FROM data
) dt
group by team
```